# WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd Get Method Failed

Tags: asp.net, ajax, get, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I have been searching around here and elsewhere on the internet searching for a solution, and have wasted too much time on this. Keep in mind I am fairly new to web design and am self taught. It is possible I just completely missing something.

When I click the but who calls the CallMeMaybe() function I will get the "Starting 1" and "passed test 1" alerts only. So my pagemethods gethello() I am assuming is not getting called, or at least not doing anything.

```
function CallMeMaybe() {
            var dest;
            // call server side method
            alert("Starting 1");

            if (typeof (PageMethods) == "undefined") {
                alert("Not Working");
            }
            else {
                alert("passed test 1");
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                PageMethods.GetHello(CallSuccess, CallFailed, dest);
            }
            alert("Sent");
        }

        function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {
            alert("success");
            var dest = document.getElementById(destCtrl);
            alert(res);
            var str = "";
            var table_result = "<table border='1'>";
            for (var i = 1; i < res.length - 1; i++) {
                str += (res[i] + "<br />");
                table_result += "<tr><td><img src='Images/img" + i + ".jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100'/></td></tr>";
            }
            table_result += "</table>";
            //document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML += str;
            document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML += table_result;
        }

        // alert message on some failure
        function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
            alert(res.get_message());
        }
```

When I run the Developer Tools in Chrome I get this:
[image: Screen Shot]

If any of you could help me or point me into the right direction that would be awesome! Like I said I have wasted too much time trying to figure this out and finally decided to come here to ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem! I had to add the following code to my Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="ManifestHandler" verb="*" path="*.manifest" type="TestWebSvc.ManifestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions,  Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```